# Mongoose query returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to simply return the result of a query via another function. In the example below, when I call **gameInit**, I need to grab a random word from the DB. **grabWord** function works fine and I can log the result within that function. It's passing back to gameInit that is the problem. I understand I need to use a callback but have failed a bunch of times with it so here i am!

```
module.exports = {
    gameInit: function(){
        var theWord = module.exports.grabWord();
        console.log(theWord); //returns undefined
    },
    grabWord: function () {
        Word.find({}, function (err, docs){ 
            rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * docs[0].words.length));
            myWord = docs[0].words[rand].word;
            return (myWord); 
            console.log(myWord); // works

        }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could pass a callback function to `grabWord`:

```
module.exports = {
  gameInit: function() {
    this.grabWord(function(word) {
      console.log('The word is ' + word);
    });
  },
  grabWord: function(cb) {
    Word.find({}, function(err, docs) {
      rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * docs[0].words.length));
      myWord = docs[0].words[rand].word;
      cb(myWord);
    });
  }
}
```

Alternatively, use Promises:

```
module.exports = {
  gameInit: function() {
    var promise = module.exports.grabWord();
    promise.then(function(word) {
      return word;
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.error('there was an error: ' + err);
    })
  },
  grabWord: function() {
    return new Promise(function(fulfill, reject) {
      Word.find({}, function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * docs[0].words.length));
          myWord = docs[0].words[rand].word;
          fullfill(myWord);
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```